# python string format whats the difference between %x and %#x (hash tag hexadecimal?)

Tags: python, string, hex, string-formatting, number-formatting

I'm porting some python back to .NET and I can't seem to figure out the difference between the `%x` and `%#x`

```
   print "%s: [%#x][%x] %s" % (message, self.eip, self.opcode,
                                    i.get_disasm())
```

Same with this function below seems it's just a plain `Hex()` function with 0x appended in front right why not just use `%x` instead then?

```
def prettify_value(value):
    if TypeOf value, (long Is int):
        value = '%#x' % value
    return value
```

Yes I can't seem to find the answer over here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Nevermind I found it it's very fine-print

The `'#'` option is only valid for integers, and only for binary, octal, or hexadecimal output. If present, it specifies that the output will be prefixed by '0b', '0o', or '0x', respectively.

Comment: wonder the rationale for downvote.  Because the OP found the answer and shared it?  Though admittedly perhaps trying it on command line or such before asking on SO would have been better.

Comment: Yah whatever I thought about deleting the question but meh there is no reason maybe some guy like me who also can't figure this out will find this helpful from a google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '#' option is only valid for integers, and only for binary, octal, or hexadecimal output. If present, it specifies that the output will be prefixed by '0b', '0o', or '0x', respectively.